# How to insert a timestamp value into the ISODate type on MongoDB by Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, isodate

The timestamp value will be transfer to the ISODate type on MongoDB by Node.js & Mongoose.

```
ex. 123456789012 ---> ISODate(xxxx)
```

But it will be save and still in Number type on MongoDB when I use Python & pymongo.

```
ex. 123456789012 ---> 123456789012 ...
```

How to insert a timestamp value into the ISODate type on MongoDB by Python?

Comment: [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert it to a `datetime.datetime` object, and save that. `pymongo`, I assume you are using that, will convert it to the right format for you.